# get all files from multiple input

Tags: javascript, php

What I want is to save all images from multiple inputs. But I am having a hard time of getting all images without using form submit. Am using ajax.

This is my HTML for example

```
<input type="file" id="image-1" name="item_file[]">
<input type="file" id="image-2" name="item_file[]">
```

And This is my ajax when submit

```
var file_data = $("#image")[0].files; 
var form_data = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
   form_data.append('item_file[]', file_data[i]);;
}

 $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,       
    type: 'POST'
 })
```

In my server side I only got 1.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid. ID's _must_ be unique within the document. Add a class instead and select the inputs based on the class. However, in this case, why not just have one file-input where you can select multiple files instead?

Comment: I updated my html input with different ids.

Comment: ...but you're still selecting `$('#image')`. Also, don't keep updating your question to fix the issues we mention in comments and answers. You should update your real code and test if it works or not. Then you can reply to us in comments to let us know if it worked or not. If you update your question, earlier comments and answers won't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use the same ID twice, you should change it

```
<input type="file" id="image1" class="image" name="item_file[]">
<input type="file" id="image2" class="image" name="item_file[]">
```

Secondly, by using `$("#image")[0]` you only get the first one, you have to iterate over the elements

```
var form_data = new FormData(), k = 0;

$('.image').each(function(_, elem) {
    var images = elem.files;

    for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
        form_data.append("image" + (++k), images[i]);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url         : 'upload.php',
    data        : form_data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(data){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Your code seems work. But in my server side I get the error image is undefine. $length = sizeof($_FILES['image']['name']);

Comment: Do you know what I am missing here?